# android how to detect click on canvas which is in a horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, click, android-canvas

Hi I have a horizontal scrollView and inside it I draw some arcs on canvas which gives me set of horizontally scrollable pie charts. Now I need to handle the on click events of each of the pie charts, could some one help me regarding the same.

```
ChartUtility sampleObject=new ChartUtility(getActivity());
sampleObject.draw(new Canvas());
ChartContainerLayout.addView(sampleViewObject);//here chartcontainerlayout is a linear layout which his present in a horizontal scrollview.
```

I have tried the ontouch event of chartutility class. But what ever is the action(either a click/horizontal scroll), the event.ACTION is being returned as "down". So how should I recognize the click event on individual items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a LinearLayout with orientation set to horizontal into the HorizontalScrollView and then make each pie chart in a separate layout within that. Then set listeners on those layouts. I would not have the click handling mixed with the scrolling.